# iptables - adding IP address range to the list of allowed sources

Tags: iptables

I've successfully restricted the access to my server (tcp traffic on port 80) using the following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT \! --src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

After executing the command my iptables look like following:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  -- !example.com          anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Lets say I want to also add access to ip address range 54.224.0.0/12 (so my server has the access from the original IP address and the newly specified range.  What do I need to do to make it happen?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Add an ACCEPT rule for the accepted range before your DROP rule.

```
iptables -I INPUT --src 54.224.0.0/12  -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```